# How to implement onClick() method on ImageView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have dynamically populated ImageViews and Textviews.

Now I have small problem with implementing onClick method on ImageView. On some ImageView click it should switch to fragment and for some click onto activity. 
here is my code - my main fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
public static String[] gridViewStrings = {
            "string1",
            "string2",
            "string3",
            "string4",
            "string5",
            "string6"
    };
    public static int[] gridViewImages = {
            R.drawable.delivery,
            R.drawable.shipping_logs,
            R.drawable.meassurement,
            R.drawable.takeovers,
            R.drawable.settings,
            R.drawable.download_data
    };


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, parent, false);
 gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAndroidGridViewAdapter(getActivity(), gridViewStrings, gridViewImages));

        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview_image);
}
```

my custom gridview adapter:

```
public class CustomAndroidGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] string;
    private final int[] Imageid;

    public CustomAndroidGridViewAdapter(Context c,String[] string,int[] Imageid ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return string.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int p) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int p) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int p, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_image);
            textView.setText(string[p]);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[p]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

**QUESTION: How to implement onClick() on ImageView and switch to fragment and activity?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface Callback:

```
public interface LaunchFragmentWithImage{
 void launchFragmentWithImage(int imageID);
}
```

Give the adapter a reference of this class below so it can call the method. Wouldn't recommend giving the adapter itself a reference to the class because its not the adapters responsibility to know who recieves the image, thus violating the Single responsibility principle of OOD, but for the sake of learning it's okay.

```
public class ClassToLaunchNewFragment extends AppCompatActivity implements 
LaunchFragmentWithImage{

  @Override //Method from interface we've defined.
  public void launchFragmentWithImage(int imageID){
     FragmentToLaunch fragmentToLaunch = FragmentToLaunch.newInstance();
     Bundle imageData = new Bundle();
     imageData.putInt(imageID, "key");
     fragmentToLaunch.setArguments(imageData);

   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() //Call replace not add
                              .replace(containerID, fragmentToLaunch)
                              .commit();

  }

}
```

In AdapterClass

```
imageViewVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view){
 fragmentToLaunchInstanceThatWasPassedIn.launchFragmentWithImage(theImageResource);
 } 


});
```

Comment: I know interfaces seem like they're not that useful because they don't do anything except define method signatures, but in reality they're an OOP programmers wet dream. I'd recommend you really learn how to use them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very useful. This is example when I'm going to specific fragment. Could you provide me few tips when different images opens different fragment?

Comment: That really depends on how you want to structure the fragments. I mean if the fragments are the same general object, but have different behaviors and states, i'd recommend just having them extend an abstract class, and then pick and chose which concretion of the abstract fragment you want to launch based on which imageview was clicked. Also if my answer helped be sure to rate as best answer and up vote it. Thanks!

Comment: It's all new to me.Could you provide me some example of that if it's not problem to you? Of course I'll accept your answer and vote up.

Comment: @Unknown19 There's a plethora of information to understand. Information i wouldn't be able to explain to you perfectly on a forum. I'll provide you direction however, so you know what to research. TOPICS: Abstract Class, OOD, "Designing to an interface", slidenerds fragment tutorial(youtube). Really the logic in programming is one part, but relatively straight forward. What matters in OOP is class structure. You can easily launch N+ fragments based on which image was clicked, simply by create n+methods to launch specific ones. That's simple to figure out, even if you're new.

Comment: What's difficult is doing it properly. You only learn how to do something like that properly by learning about OOP, and OOD.

Answer (score 3):

```
public DlgOutletListAdapter(Context context, List<WrapperOutlet> wrapperOutletList, View.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.wrapperOutletList = wrapperOutletList;
        this.listener = listener;      //---> pass in listener....

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return wrapperOutletList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return wrapperOutletList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_dlg_outlet_list, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            viewHolder.ll_dlg_outlet_list_container.setOnClickListener(listener);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (!wrapperOutletList.isEmpty()) {
            WrapperOutlet wrapperOutlet = wrapperOutletList.get(position);
            Outlet outlet = wrapperOutlet.getOutlet();
            if (outlet != null) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(outlet.getTel())){
                    viewHolder.ivCall.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_call2);
                    viewHolder.tvCall.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.medium_gray));
                       viewHolder.ll_dlg_outlet_list_dialer.setOnClickListener(null);
                } else {
                    viewHolder.ivCall.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_call);
                    viewHolder.tvCall.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.fresh_teal));
                    viewHolder.ll_dlg_outlet_list_dialer.setOnClickListener(listener);    
                }


            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Pass in listener. Give you an example above. code below is where you call the adapter in fragment. My fragment implements View.OnClickListener

```
lv_dlg_outlet_list.setAdapter(new DlgOutletListAdapter(activity, wrapperOutletList, this));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grid = new View(mContext);
grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, null);
```

why are you pointing the grid variable to two separate View objects?

Comment: Mistake, I was doing something and forgot to delete first line.

Comment: oh alright. Well you gotta be as specific with your answers as you have to be with coding. Are you asking HOW to launch a new fragment instance, or asking HOW to launch a new activity?

Comment: Both, because some of those ImageViews will go to fragment and some to activity, but let's focus on fragments.

Comment: in your adapter class, set an onClickListener on your image view. Create a callback interface that is to be implemented by the class that handles fragment launching, define a callback method that accepts a int parameter. Call that method in the onClickListener of your imageview, give it the int resource of the image and set it as a fragment argument in the fragment you want to launch. Then within the fragment that you wanted to launch simply inflate the image view with the int variable

Comment: I'm having a little problem with interface

Answer (score 0):

```
if (convertView == null) {

        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_image);
        textView.setText(string[p]);
        imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[p]);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(choosedPosition){
                case 0:do something;break;
                case 1:do something;break;
                ...
            }
        }
        });
        }
```

It's just an example and can't running.