# How to get correct imageview from the position where button is clicked in Listview

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, getview

I have a custom listview with image and text. I am loading image into Listview using the Glide library.  Sometimes only text will be there without image. Now, I want to share the imageview and text using Share intent, for this purpose i have created a button. I have created a Onclick Listener for the button and it is displayed along with the each item in Listview. When i click on the button it will send the imageview to process then convert into bitmap and then it will be shared. 
Problem here is when i click on button the imageview of particular position is not selected instead different imageview selected. Please help.

I have OnItem listener on Imageview to display it in full screen and zooming.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final descusers du = dusers.get(position);
        String username = du.loginname;
        String descCrip=du.descCrip;
        Limage = du.image;
        long Ptime = du.Ptime;
        profile = du.profile;


        if(convertView==null) {
            viewholder = new Viewholder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ds).inflate(R.layout.customlist, null);
            viewholder.uname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            viewholder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            viewholder.time = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            viewholder.iview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageList);
            viewholder.civ = (CircleImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            viewholder.share = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.share);

            Glide.with(convertView.getContext()).load(du.profile).placeholder(R.drawable.place).dontAnimate()
                    .centerCrop().signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                    .into(viewholder.civ);

            convertView.setTag(viewholder);
        }else {

            viewholder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        viewholder.uname.setText(username);
        viewholder.desc.setText(descCrip);

        if (!Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(Limage).matches()) {
           // viewholder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewholder.iview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {

            Glide.with(convertView.getContext()).load(Limage).centerCrop().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(viewholder.iview);
            viewholder.iview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        final View finalConvertView = convertView;
        viewholder.iview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                Dialog builder = new Dialog(listdisplay, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
                 builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                 builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                         new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
                 builder.setContentView(R.layout.imager);

                 ImageView image = (ImageView) builder.findViewById(R.id.image);

                 Glide.with(finalConvertView.getContext()).load(du.image)
                         .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(image);

                 builder.show();
             }
         });

        viewholder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //onShareItem(v);
                Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(viewholder.iview);
                if (bmpUri != null) {
                    // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                    // Launch sharing dialog for image
                    listdisplay.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));

                } else {
                    // ...sharing failed, handle error
                }
             }
        });


        return convertView;
    }
```

How to get the correct Imageview from the position where button is clicked.

Comment: You may passed the onclick listener from outside of the adapter. [see the answer i posted before]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710179/how-to-implement-onclick-method-on-imageview/38710636#38710636

Comment: show me your adapter constructor

Comment: @RahulChaudhary -      DescAdapter(listdisplay ds, ArrayList<descusers> dusers, Activity listdisplay) {
            this.ds = ds;
            this.dusers = dusers;
            this.listdisplay = listdisplay;

        }

Comment: class descusers have image . am i right

Comment: @RahulChaudhary - Yes

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: are you able to show image in pop up screen

Comment: Yes i am able to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

```
    Dialog builder = new Dialog(listdisplay, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
    builder.setContentView(R.layout.imager);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) builder.findViewById(R.id.image);

    Glide.with(finalConvertView.getContext()).load(du.image)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(image);

    Glide
            .with(finalConvertView.getContext())
            .load(du.image)
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                    image.setImageBitmap(resource); // Possibly runOnUiThread()
                    profileImage=resourec;
                }
            });

    builder.show();
}
```

});

Comment: I am using button for sharing and for Imageview there is a listener already which is used for opening image full screen. Problem is when i click on button i need to pass the Imageview in same position to getbitmap for sharing. I am not getting correct imageView to pass when i click on Share button.

Comment: declare profileImage as bitmap or first try to download bitmap with Glide libray and use it

Comment: Its worked with the using Glide with Simple Target. Thanks Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

You can user **position** for it in

```
         **@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         }**
```

it's give correct tap position of list item.